# How do I get the size of an individual cell of a wx.GridSizer?

Tags: wxpython, sizer

I'm wondering if I could get the size of an individual cell of a `wx.GridSizer` after calling `Fit()`. If so, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
item = sizer.GetItem(index)
size = item.GetSize()
```

How to find the item's index? From the [documentation](http://file:///media/sda1/Downloads/wxPython-2.8.9.2/docs/api/wx.GridSizer-class.html),

> Items are placed in the cells of the
>   grid in the order they are added, in
>   row-major order. In other words, the
>   first row is filled first, then the
>   second, and so on until all items have
>   been added. (If neccessary, additional
>   rows will be added as items are
>   added.)